# Detectar un conjunto de palabras en especifico con expresiónes regulares

Tags: python, regex

Tengo una lista de productos de una base de datos de ejemplo que tienen el siguiente formato:

- 0000 prod-cod Nombre del producto

Como se observa es una linea de texto la cual se compone de 3 "divisiones" por decir algo, mi problema es que necesico separar esa información para obtener los 3 datos por separado sin embargo la segunda columna **prod-cod** no es una constante si no que suele variar un poco por ejemplo:

1. 6869 **TC205** Esponja limpiadora
2. 0184 **31245** TIRA LED con **345** Leds
3. 6468 **ALA-140** Alarma
4. 3219 **WI.156** Cable Tipo C de **3.0A**

Como se observa la segunda palabra que representa el códgo del producto suele tener esas 4 variantes, el problema es que al hacer una regla para aceptar esos 4 parametros puede tomar en cuenta los parametros del nombre que cuenten con esas caracteristicas por lo que trate estas soluciones:

**Crear un filtro para cada una de las 3 variantes**

```
re.sub("[0-9]{4,4}","") # Su función es buscar los primeros 4 digitos númericos

re.sub("^\s[\w]+-+[\w/]+","") # Su función es buscar el código del producto
```

Finalmente deberia quedar el nombre del producto, pero dado a que varia el código del producto no encuentro una forma de que unicamente me devuelva la segunda palabra de toda la fila de texto que representa el código interno del producto.

¿Existe alguna manera de que regex me devuelva algo asi?

- `0000` `Prod-Code` `Nombre del producto`

Comment: ¿No será más fácil hacer un tipo “split” y separar en los primeros 2 espacios?

Comment: que tal, consulta, las columnas son simpre las mismas ? 3 en este caso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrias usar la siguiente expresion regular:

```
([0-9]{4,4})\s(?P<codigoproducto>[\w/]+)\s(?P<nombredelproducto>[a-zA-Z\s]+)
```

La notacion `(?P<codigoproducto>expresion_regular)` nos permite asignar un nombre a la expresion regular

esto nos daria la siguiente maquina de estados:

[image: maquina de estados de la expresion regular]

Este tipo de expresiones regulares con nombres de grupos sirven mucho para relizar remplazos rapidos en un texto, por ejemplo:

```
# coding=utf8
# define la codificacion del documento para compatibilidad con Python 2.x

import re

regex = r"([0-9]{4,4})\s(?P<codigoproducto>[\w/]+)\s(?P<nombredelproducto>[a-zA-Z\s]+)"

test_str = "6869 TC205 Esponja limpiadora"

subst = "\\g<codigoproducto>-\\g<nombredelproducto>"

# Se puede especificar el numero de remplazos cambiando el 4to argumento
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Nota: para compatibilidad con Python 2.7, usa ur"" como prefijo de la regex y u"" como prefijo de las cadenas de prueba y substitucion.
```

En este caso la salida seria:

> TC205-Esponja limpiadora

Si necesitaras el primer grupo que no tiene nombre puedes referenciarlo mediante `\g<1>`

### Mejoras

Probando vi que tienes mas caracteres de los que contemplabas en tus expresiones regulares originales, asi que seguramente quedaria mejor asi:

```
([0-9]{4,4})\s(?P<codigoproducto>[\w\./]+)\s(?P<nombredelproducto>[a-zA-Z0-9\.\s]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te complicas demasiado. Si son tres columnas y las dos primeras están separadas por espacios, lo más sencillo es usar [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```py
ref, prod_code, descrip = product.split(maxsplit=2)
```

El método `str.split()` *rebana* la cadena de caracteres en fragmentos separados por espacios en blanco. Como sólo nos interesa los dos primeros fragmentos, usamos el parámetro `maxplit=2` para que no siga rebanando una vez obtenidos los dos primeros fragmentos. Lo que queda como resto de la cadena (tercer fragmento) será la descripción.

Si no usáramos `maxsplit` para limitar el número de fragmentos, se seguiría rebanando la descripción por los espacios en blancos que tenga. Además de no ser lo que queremos, nos indeterminaría el número de fragmentos que podamos tener, lo que nos complica un poco el código.

Comment: y que es maxplit?

Comment: Concuerdo con Ruslan Lopez con que sería una buena adición  a la respuesta explicar lo que hace split y maxsplit. O minimo un link.